# Table of content with page number and quadrant

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, table-of-contents

I want to create the table of contents automatically and depending on where the linked word appears on the two columned pages there should also be mentioned the quadrant after the page number in the TOC.

For example if the linked word stands in the top right quadrant on page 123 the corresponding entry in the TOC should list it as "123 C" or similar. Top left is A, bottom left is B, top right is C and bottom right is D.

Any suggestions how to do it? Do I have to script this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to make a Table of Contents and the built-in tool can't perform the formatting the way you like (and if I'm right about this, it can't), then the next-best thing is to utilize cross-references. It's more time-intensive to setup, but it's also format-proof.

This may seem counterintuitive if you've always made TOC's with the TOC tool and not with cross-references, but first, you want to format the Table of Contents how you'd like it to look (with your quandrants) with dummy text. Once you have the look down, you can link up the dummy text and automatically replace it with the section headers.

Create two cross-reference formats, one for the name of your section and one for the page number. Link both to a paragraph style that only exists on your section pages (a header, for instance).

Then, cross reference the titles and pages separately, so that you can place them anywhere you want on your quadrant without worrying about them messing up the layout.